# Rails: Net::OpenTimeout in ContatosController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't know the reason why this error **Net::OpenTimeout in ContatosController#create** is appearing. I have the following code in app/controllers/contatos_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @contato = Contato.new(contato_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contato.save
        ContatoMailer.mensagem(@contato).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to contatos_path, notice: 'Obrigado por enviar sua mensagem! Em breve, responderemos.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contato }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contato.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In app/mailers/contato_mailer.rb:

```
class ContatoMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "myemail@gmail.com"

    def mensagem(contato)
        mail(:to => "myemail@gmail.com", :subject => "Subject")            
    end
end
```

In config/initializers/setup_mail.rb:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'domain.com',
  :user_name            => 'myemail@gmail.com',
  :password             => 'secret',
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :ssl                  => true
}
```

And, of course, the template in app/views/contato_mailer/mensagem.html.erb.

When I submit a new message from the form, Rails returns **"execution expired"** with focus on **"ContatoMailer.mensagem(@contato).deliver"**.

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `domain:` key to point to `'gmail'` so it should read:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => 'gmail.com',
  :user_name            => 'myemail@gmail.com',
  :password             => 'secret',
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :ssl                  => true
}
```

I think it is timing out because it doesn't know what domain.com is respective to your settings.